# Using "collectively comprising" to mean "which, in all, make up"

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-requests, syntactic-analysis, formality

I have a sentence `It has 42 cities collectively comprising 188 villages.`

I am thinking of using the phrase `collectively comprising` to be a more formal form of `which, in all, make up` to mean something like:

`It has 42 cities which, in all, make up 188 villages`.

Is it grammatically correct to use `collectively comprising` for this matter? Or are there better alternatives which convey the idea more clearly?